# Can you send & receive data inside Unity3D?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I was wondering if I could send and receive data e.g (user's name and high score) to the database or receive a confirmation message inside Unity 3D or update bonus and specials points etc.

Any help will be appreciated! Please guide me to a reference or provide code snippets as I am not an advanced game developer.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, in particular I suggest looking at the [WWW class](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/WWW.html).

Of course, you might need to have a better grounding in the basics - in which case I'd recommend C# tutorials, the unity3d forums and a whole lot of perspiration.

Comment: Can this be done using Javascript? Can you send me some references or links to this tutorials?

Comment: Unityscript, yes - but I recommend C#. Tutorial wise do what my post said - google C# tuts and take a look at the unity3d forums.

Answer (score 0):

You can send data via http in unity using javascript. The simplest way is create http server and interract with this server from unity.
Read a good tutorial about it:
http://unity-tutorials.blogspot.com/